# Example of sending an email with attachment via Amazon in Java

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services

Does anyone have an example of sending an email, with an attachment, via Amazon SES (in Java)?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe a little bit late, but you can use this code (you also need Java Mail):

```
public class MailSender
{
      private Transport AWSTransport;
      ...
      //Initialize transport
      private void initAWSTransport() throws MessagingException
      {
        String keyID = <your key id>
        String secretKey = <your secret key>
        MailAWSCredentials credentials = new MailAWSCredentials();
        credentials.setCredentials(keyID, secretKey);
        AmazonSimpleEmailService ses = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);
        Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "aws");
        props.setProperty("mail.aws.user", credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId());
        props.setProperty("mail.aws.password", credentials.getAWSSecretKey());
        AWSsession = Session.getInstance(props);
        AWStransport = new AWSJavaMailTransport(AWSsession, null);
        AWStransport.connect();
      }

  public void sendEmail(byte[] attachment)
  {
    //mail properties
    String senderAddress = <Sender address>;
    String recipientAddress = <Recipient address>;
    String subject = <Mail subject>;
    String text = <Your text>;
    String mimeTypeOfText = <MIME type of text part>;
    String fileMimeType = <MIME type of your attachment>;
    String fileName = <Name of attached file>;

    initAWSTransport();

    try
    {
      // Create new message
      Message msg = new MimeMessage(AWSsession);
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderAddress));
      msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipientAddress));
      msg.setSubject(subject);

      //Text part
      Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      messageBodyPart.setContent(text, mimeTypeOfText);
      multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

      //Attachment part
      if (attachment != null && attachment.length != 0)
      {
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment,fileMimeType);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
      }
      msg.setContent(multipart);

      //send message
      msg.saveChanges();
      AWSTransport.sendMessage(msg, null);
    } catch (MessagingException e){...}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm after.

Comment: I am not able to find the class "MailAWSCredentials" and "AWStransport". Kindly help

Answer (score 15):

Maybe a little bit late too.
Alternative to send mail using Java Mail and Amazon Raw Mail Sender

```
public static void sendMail(String subject, String message, byte[] attachement, String fileName, String contentType, String from, String[] to) {
    try {
        // JavaMail representation of the message
        Session s = Session.getInstance(new Properties(), null);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(s);

        // Sender and recipient
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        for (String toMail : to) {
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toMail));
        }

        // Subject
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);

        // Add a MIME part to the message
        MimeMultipart mimeBodyPart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
        part.setContent(message, MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        mimeBodyPart.addBodyPart(part);

        // Add a attachement to the message
        part = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachement, contentType);
        part.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        part.setFileName(fileName);
        mimeBodyPart.addBodyPart(part);

        mimeMessage.setContent(mimeBodyPart);

        // Create Raw message
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mimeMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
        RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));

        // Credentials
        String keyID = "";// <your key id>
        String secretKey = "";// <your secret key>
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(keyID, secretKey);
        AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);

        // Send Mail
        SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
        rawEmailRequest.setDestinations(Arrays.asList(to));
        rawEmailRequest.setSource(from);
        client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);

    } catch (IOException | MessagingException e) {
        // your Exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html has an example that sends both html and text bodies (with an attachment, of course). FWIW, here is the conversion and reorganization of its Java code to Kotlin. The dependency is `'com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2'`.

```
data class Attachment(val fileName: String, val contentType: String, val data: ByteArray)

fun sendEmailWithAttachment(from: String, to: List<String>, subject: String, htmlBody: String, textBody: String,
                            attachment: Attachment) {
    try {
        val textPart = MimeBodyPart().apply {
            setContent(textBody, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
        }

        val htmlPart = MimeBodyPart().apply {
            setContent(htmlBody, "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
        }

        // Create a multipart/alternative child container.
        val childPart = MimeMultipart("alternative").apply {
            // Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
            addBodyPart(textPart)
            addBodyPart(htmlPart)
        }

        // Create a wrapper for the HTML and text parts.
        val childWrapper = MimeBodyPart().apply {
            setContent(childPart)
        }

        // Define the attachment
        val dataSource = ByteArrayDataSource(attachment.data, attachment.contentType)
        // val dataSource = FileDataSource(filePath)  // if using file directly
        val attPart = MimeBodyPart().apply {
            dataHandler = DataHandler(dataSource)
            fileName = attachment.fileName
        }

        // Create a multipart/mixed parent container.
        val parentPart = MimeMultipart("mixed").apply {
            // Add the multipart/alternative part to the message.
            addBodyPart(childWrapper)
            addBodyPart(attPart)  // Add the attachment to the message.
        }

        // JavaMail representation of the message
        val s = Session.getDefaultInstance(Properties())
        val mimeMessage = MimeMessage(s).apply {
            // Add subject, from and to lines
            this.subject = subject
            setFrom(InternetAddress(from))
            to.forEach() {
                addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress(it))
            }

            // Add the parent container to the message.
            setContent(parentPart)
        }

        // Create Raw message
        val rawMessage = with(ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            mimeMessage.writeTo(this)
            RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(this.toByteArray()))
        }

        val rawEmailRequest = SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage).apply {
            source = from
            setDestinations(to)
        }

        // Send Mail
        val client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build()
        client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest)
        println("Email with attachment sent to $to")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated, cleaned up version with logging and check for production.

```
public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String body, String attachment, String mimeType, String fileName) {
    if (to == null) return;

    String environment = System.getProperty("ENVIRONMENT", System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT"));
    String logMessage;
    if (environment != null && environment.equals("production")) {
        logMessage = "Sent email to " + to + ".";
    } else {
        to = "success@simulator.amazonses.com";
        logMessage = "Email sent to success@simulator.amazonses.com because $ENVIRONMENT != 'production'";
    }

    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk.html
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
        message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
            MimeMultipart msg = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
                MimeBodyPart wrap = new MimeBodyPart();
                    MimeMultipart msgBody = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
                        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                        textPart.setContent(body, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
                        htmlPart.setContent(body,"text/html; charset=UTF-8");
                    msgBody.addBodyPart(textPart);
                    msgBody.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
                wrap.setContent(msgBody);
            msg.addBodyPart(wrap);
                MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
                att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(attachment, mimeType));
                att.setFileName(fileName);
//                  DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(attachment);
//                  att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
//                  att.setFileName(fds.getName());
            msg.addBodyPart(att);
        message.setContent(msg);

        AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder
                .standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
        message.writeTo(System.out);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(outputStream);
        RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));
        SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
//                      .withConfigurationSetName(CONFIGURATION_SET);
        client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
        Logger.info(this.getClass(), "sendEmail()", logMessage);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.info(this.getClass(), "sendEmail()", "The email was not sent. Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk.html

> You use a shared credentials file to pass your AWS access key ID and secret access key. As an alternative to using a shared credentials file, you can specify your AWS access key ID and secret access key by setting two environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, respectively).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

libraries: 
net.sf.jasperreports 
com.lowagie 
spring-boot-starter-mail

```
@Autowired
private AmazonSimpleEmailServiceAsync amazonSimpleEmailService;

public void send(String destination, byte[] attachment) {
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties());

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setSubject(subject);

            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            ByteArrayDataSource byteArrayDataSource =
                    new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
            mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(byteArrayDataSource));
            mimeBodyPart.setFileName(nameAttachment);

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(outputStream);
            RawMessage rawMessage = new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));
            SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
            rawEmailRequest.withDestinations(destination);
            rawEmailRequest.withSource(mail);

            amazonSimpleEmailService.sendRawEmailAsync(rawEmailRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```