# Sending Emails using Python from Amazon SES with attachments

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, web2py

We are using python for developing our apps and deploying on GAE. We would like to send emails through Amazon SES with attachments.  All of the ones that I have seen do not have attachment support. The reason I need to use to Amazon SES to send emails is bcoz I have to send emails from domain other than google's.

Are there any libs that allow me do that ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: Not for Python, but fo Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963439/example-of-sending-an-email-with-attachment-via-amazon-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create MIEMApplication() instance for each attachment and add it to the MIMEMultipart instance. Solution is available in the blog post: http://codeadict.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/send-e-mails-with-attachment-in-python/