# How to send email with a file attachment using aws ses and java?

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services

I have checked all over aws documentation but didn't find any example or text,which can guide about "How to send email with a file attachment using aws ses(simple email service) and java ?"

I need to write following logic:

- Receive a set of data
- convert this data to CSV file
- Create a file e.g. abc.csv
- Prepare a email body, add this attachment and text
- Send it

I have followed below examples, these explains the process something like this:
Example: [image]
Image Source: [http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java)

[I have followed this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963439/example-of-sending-an-email-with-attachment-via-amazon-in-java), but fail to understand this part:

```
//Attachment part
  if (attachment != null && attachment.length != 0)

   {
    
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment,fileMimeType);

    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

    messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

  }

  msg.setContent(multipart);
```

also this Followed this example: [https://mintylikejava.blogspot.in/2014/05/example-of-sending-email-with-multipal.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170311071200/http://mintylikejava.blogspot.in:80/2014/05/example-of-sending-email-with-multipal.html)

But I didn't understand:

```
   DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);

      attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
```

**How I can define source, If I am preparing a file on same function** e.g.

```
File myFile = new File("TestFile_"+ LocalDateTime.now().toString()+ ".csv");

        try {
            fop = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

            byte[] contentInBytes = textBody.getData().getBytes();

            fop.write(contentInBytes);
            fop.flush();
            fop.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Not sure what exactly I am missing here?**

---

#### Solved

**Below function I wrote to solve this problem (Added on 29th-Dec-2016):**

```
public String sendReceivedOutputAsEmailToUsers(EmailProperties emailProperties,String fileContents , String toEmails) throws InternalErrorException
    {
        String[] toAddressesInput = null;
        // Get the toArrays
        toAddressesInput = toEmails.split(",");

        BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(PropertyManager.getSetting("awsAccessKeyId"),
                PropertyManager.getSetting("awsSecretAccessKey"));

        // Construct an object to contain the recipient address.
        Destination destination = new Destination().withToAddresses(toAddressesInput);


        // Create the subject and body of the message.
        // emailRequest.getSubject() - need to write the format of message

        // Prepare Subject
        String subject = CommonStrings.defaultSubject + " Generated at: " + LocalDateTime.now().toString();

        if(emailProperties.getSubject()!=null)
        {
           subject =  emailProperties.getSubject() + " Generated at: " + LocalDateTime.now().toString();;
        }
        String inputFileName = null;

        if(emailProperties.getAttachmentName() != null)
        {
            inputFileName = emailProperties.getAttachmentName() + "_" + LocalDateTime.now().toString() + ".csv";

        }else
        {
            inputFileName = "GenreatedReport__" + LocalDateTime.now().toString() + ".csv";
        }

        Content textBody = null;
        FileOutputStream fop = null;

        if(emailProperties.getIsBody().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            if(emailProperties.getBodyMessagePrefix()!= null) {
                textBody = new Content().withData("\n\n" + emailProperties.getBodyMessagePrefix() + "\n\n" +fileContents);
            } else
            {
                textBody = new Content().withData("\n\n" +fileContents);
            }

        }

        AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = null;
        client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(basicAWSCredentials);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        // sets SMTP server properties
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "aws");
        props.setProperty("mail.aws.user", PropertyManager.getSetting("awsAccessKeyId"));
        props.setProperty("mail.aws.password",  PropertyManager.getSetting("awsSecretAccessKey"));

        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);

        // Create an email
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        // Sender and recipient
        try {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(CommonStrings.adminEmailAddress));
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new InternalErrorException(ExceptionStrings.EX_EMAIL + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }

        // msg.setRecipient( Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("abc  <abc@gmail.com>"));

        // for multiple Recipient
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[toAddressesInput.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < toAddresses.length; i++)
        {
            try {
                toAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(toAddressesInput[i]);
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                throw new InternalErrorException(ExceptionStrings.EX_EMAIL + ":" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            msg.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new InternalErrorException(ExceptionStrings.EX_EMAIL + ":" + e.getMessage());

        }

        // creates message part
        BodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();

        try {
            part.setContent(textBody.getData(), "text/html");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new InternalErrorException(ExceptionStrings.EX_EMAIL + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Add a MIME part to the message
        MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        try {
            mp.addBodyPart(part);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new InternalErrorException(ExceptionStrings.EX_EMAIL + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }
        BodyPart attachment = null;
        attachment = new MimeBodyPart();

        try {
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileContents);
            attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attachment.setText(fileContents);
            attachment.setFileName(inputFileName);
            mp.addBodyPart(attachment);
            msg.setContent(mp);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new InternalErrorException(ExceptionStrings.EX_EMAIL + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Print the raw email content on the console
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            msg.writeTo(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InternalErrorException(ExceptionStrings.EX_EMAIL + ":" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new InternalErrorException(ExceptionStrings.EX_EMAIL + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Send Mail
        RawMessage rm = new RawMessage();
        rm.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(out.toString().getBytes()));
        client.sendRawEmail(new SendRawEmailRequest().withRawMessage(rm));

        logger.info("email sent : success");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have solved it by making some changes on the attachment part like : DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileContents); ( here fileContents String Data). And : attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); Also gave the file name like :    attachment.setFileName("TestFile_" + LocalDateTime.now().toString() + ".csv"); , And then added attachment part to MimeMultipart mp message. and then it worked !

Comment: Maybe you could post the complete source as the answer. I too have been looking everywhere!

Comment: @MarkMurphy Mark I have update the answer by adding the function which finally I used for one of my work item.